# Full Join Query

Tags: postgresql, join

I am doing a full join query from two tables.

```
SELECT  
i.idinasistencia,  i.fecha, i.valor, i.justificado,
h.id, p.nombres, p.apellido_paterno, p.apellido_materno,
p.rut_persona
FROM historialalumno h 
FULL JOIN inasistencias i
    ON i.idhistorialalumnofk = h.id
INNER JOIN alumno a 
    ON a.idalumno = h.idalumnofk
LEFT JOIN persona p 
    ON p.idpersona= a.idpersonafk
WHERE h.idcursofk = 8
    AND h.idcolegiofk = 1
    AND h.idanioacademicofk = 1
    **AND i.fecha = '06/07/2016'**
```

But I need to filter the rows by date (`fecha`), that field exist only in one of the tables, then the query result only bring the rows from one table. But I need to bring all the rows from both tables, no matter if date (`fecha`) no exist in the other table. I know the columns possibly show 'null' value but is ok for me.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get that by simply adding the additional criteria to the full join instead of the where clause.

```
 on i.idhistorialalumnofk = h.id and i.fecha = '06/07/2016'
```

it seems odd to be needing a FULL join here but we don't really have much info so that might actually be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subquery:

```
...
FROM historialalumno h
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM inasistencias
   WHERE  fecha = '2016-06-07'
   ) i ON i.idhistorialalumnofk = h.id
...
```

And don't use ambiguous date formats. Use unambiguous ISO format.